# Why is my RSS feed not working?

Tags: permalinks, rss, feed

I have the following [blog](http://www.talentheromedia.com/the-recruiting-rundown-blog/) on a WordPress site. The [RSS feed](http://www.talentheromedia.com/the-recruiting-rundown-blog/feed/) does not contain a list of the posts. Any thoughts on what is going on?

**UPDATE**

I noticed that my blog index page was located at http://www.talentheromedia.com/the-recruiting-rundown-blog/ whereas the blog posts path began with http://www.talentheromedia.com/the-recruiting-rundown/ (notice the missing "-blog"). I changed the blog index page to http://www.talentheromedia.com/the-recruiting-rundown/ but it did not fix the feed.

Comment: Try rebuilding your permalinks. Go to Settings >> Permalinks and click Save which will flush and rebuild them. Also, are these standard WordPress posts, or are they a custom post type? Lastly, if you switch to the default WordPress theme and test, do they show up in your rss feed?

Comment: @IndustrialThemes I did the Permalinks flush but that did not work. They are standard WP posts. I tested another theme but it made no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your feed is there. You can check this by opening the source code of your homepage and find these lines:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Talent Hero Media &raquo; Feed" href="http://www.talentheromedia.com/feed/" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Talent Hero Media &raquo; Comments Feed" href="http://www.talentheromedia.com/comments/feed/" />
```

If you click on the first link you will be led to the source code of the actual location and presto ... there's your feed. Unfortunately, when you run the url `.../feed/` you are rerouted to the comments feed. Actually `.../comments/feed/` sends your to `.../feed/` as well. If you look in the source code of the comments feed you see:

```
<atom:link href="http://www.talentheromedia.com/the-recruiting-rundown/feed/" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
```

So, for some reason (presumably a plugin) your comments feed url is overwriting the post feed url. Disable all plugins and switch them on one by one to find the offender.

Comment: Actually, it appears that my feed is available at http://www.talentheromedia.com/feed/. I was trying http://www.talentheromedia.com/the-recruiting-rundown/feed. Thanks for helping me figure this out.